# Sending bytes on outputstream with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with a custom network protocol that requires a precise bytes sequence to do a sort of handshake, as example the first call should send a body like:

`0003joy` that, translated in a `[UInt8]` should be `[0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x6a,0x6f,0x79]` 
(please note that the first 4 numbers should not be converted to char... I'm sending the numeric value, as per protocol request)

I'm trying to send this sequence to an `outputstream` but I'm wondering if the steps I'm following are correct, here is my code... do you see anything strange that might prevent this sequence to reach the server?

```
// Create Bytes sequence
let bytes:[UInt8] = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x6a,0x6f,0x79]

// Convert Bytes array do Data
let dt = Data(bytes)

// Send Data to stream 
_ = dt.withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let pointer = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
        return
    }
    outputStream.write(pointer, maxLength: dt.count)
}
```

Also, do I need to convert the bytes sequence to Data? is there a way to send bytes sequence directly into the socket without converting it into Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code but the conversion to `Data` is not needed:

```
bytes.withUnsafeBytes {
    guard let pointer = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else {
        return
    }
    outputStream.write(pointer, maxLength: bytes.count)
}
```

since `[UInt8]` conforms to `ContiguousBytes`.

Actually, the following is also possible:

```
bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    guard let baseAddress = $0.baseAddress else { return }
    outputStream.write(baseAddress, maxLength: bytes.count)
}
```